# Construct an affine transformation of a plane given the images of three points

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, analytic-geometry, plane-geometry

Consider a plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ and an affine transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ that maps points $A,B,C$ to points $A',B',C'$ correspondingly. We know that $A,B,C$ are not on the same straight line and so $T$ is determined uniquely. Given an arbitrary point $M$ how to find $T(M)$?

Basically, I'm trying to write a program that takes as input 14 numbers—the coordinates of the points $A,B,C, A',B',C',M$ and outputs two numbers—the coordinates of $M'=T(M)$, provided $A,B,C$ are not on the same straight line. How should I proceed?

Comment: To be clear, do you want $T$ to be *linear* or *affine*?  If linear, you only need to know how $T$ maps *two* points.  But it sounds like you might want an affine map.

Comment: @Bye_World, Yes, I meant affine. I got confused with the terminology

Comment: @Bye_World, can I use two points to find linear transform and then the third one to determine the shift?

Comment: Yes that's another way to do it.  But then your two "points" need to be vectors formed by the three (actual) points.  I.e. $\vec{AB}=B-A$ and $\vec{AC}=C-A$, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general affine map in the plane will be of the form $$T(x,y) = (ax+by+c,dx+ey+f)$$  From the three point-image pairs you can construct the system of equations
$$A_1' = aA_1+bA_2 + c \\ A_2' = dA_1 + eA_2 + f \\ B_1' = aB_1+bB_2 + c \\ B_2' = dB_1 + eB_2 + f \\ C_1' = aC_1+bC_2 + c \\ C_2' = dC_1 + eC_2 + f$$
This can be written as a matrix equation:
$$\begin{bmatrix} A_1 & A_2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & A_1 & A_2 & 1 \\ B_1 & B_2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & B_1 & B_2 & 1 \\ C_1 & C_2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & C_1 & C_2 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \\ e \\ f\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A_1' \\ A_2' \\ B_1'\\ B_2' \\ C_1' \\ C_2'\end{bmatrix}$$

Solve it to get the constants that describe your affine map.

Comment: Note that in my notation, the point $A$ has coordinates $(A_1,A_2)$.

Comment: BTW, if the $6\times 6$ matrix scares you (which it shouldn't since you're programming this and thus won't be solving it by hand), the equation can easily be broken down into two equations with $3\times 3$ matrices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Why the three 0, 0, 0 are added in every row? Is it to make the matrix commute? And can you please describe me the reason why the first sparse matrix in the equation Ax =b has been represented in such way? I know it's a naive question. But I want to understand.

Answer (score 2):

If you use homogeneous coordinates, the map is quite easy to construct. Recall that the columns of a transformation matrix are images of basis vectors, so the homogeneous matrix $$V=\begin{bmatrix}A&B&C\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$ maps the standard basis to the vectors with coordinates given by $A$, $B$, $C$, respectively, in the standard basis. The inverse of this matrix maps these vectors to the standard basis vectors, so $$T=\begin{bmatrix}A'&B'&C'\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A&B&C\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$ is the matrix that performs the desired mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You need only 2 points for that, but have to know that they are linearly independent ( if you are programming it, it should be easy, put every 2 vectors as rows of a matrix, use row reduction and get whether they are linearly independent). Take these 2 vectors after the linear transformation, say A' and B', put these 2 vectors as columns in a matrix, and do matrix multiplication with the vector M, and there you get it, the vector M'. 
pay attention that if A,B and C, are linearly dependent, you need more vectors to map the transformation.

Hope this will be useful. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry for the confusion, I messed up the terminology, I meant affine transformation.

Answer (score 0):

If you treat $A'$, $B'$, and $C'$ as vectors $\vec{A}'$, $\vec{B}'$, and $\vec{C}'$, the answer can be written in the following neat form
$$
\vec{P}(p_x; p_y) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
        \begin{pmatrix}
            0   & \vec{A}' & \vec{B}' & \vec{C}' \\
            p_x & A_x      & B_x      & C_x      \\
            p_y & A_y      & B_y      & C_y      \\
            1   & 1        & 1        & 1        \\
        \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
        \begin{pmatrix}
            A_x & B_x & C_x \\
            A_y & B_y & C_y \\
            1   & 1   & 1   \\
        \end{pmatrix}
},
$$
where $p_x$ and $p_y$ are coordinates of the point you are mapping.

For more details on how this all works you may check "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner%27s_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)", where authors of the equation elaborate on theory behind it. In the guide there is exactly the same 2D example solved as the one you are interested in.
The same authors recently published "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)"  (ResearchGate as well). They discuss many practical examples there, e.g. show that the same equation may be used for color interpolation or Phong shading. You may want to check it if you want to see this equation in action.