# 2D coordinates after shifting, scaling and rotation

Tags: geometry

Suppose that there are $N=4$ points ($A,B,C,D$) on a 2D space. Connect the four points, and then form a quadrilateral $Q$. After unknown linear transformation (shifting, scaling and rotation), we obtian a new quadrilateral $Q'$. If we know the new coordinates of $Q'$, namely

$A'=(x'_1,y'_1),B'=(x'_2,y'_2),C'=(x'_3,y'_3),D'=(x'_4,y'_4).$

Also we know the coordinates of $A,B,C$

$A=(x_1,y_1),B=(x_2,y_2),C=(x_3,y_3).$

The points $A,B,C$ are not colinear.

**Question**: How to obtain the coordinates of point $D$?

Generally, if $N=100$, what's the solution?

Similarly, we konw the coordinates of $Q'=\{(x'_1,y'_1),(x'_2,y'_2),...,(x'_{100},y'_{100})\}$, and the non-colinear three points $A=(x_1,y_1),B=(x_2,y_2),C=(x_3,y_3).$

---

To make the question be more interesting, I further consider that even after a rigid transformation, it is unlikely that the known points will precisely align, since the pratical measurements used to localize the points are likely to have errors.

I also found a solution, named coordinate system registration:

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Shahriar_Negahdaripour/publication/234136431_Closed-Form_Solution_of_Absolute_Orientation_using_Orthonormal_Matrices/links/53cf5fe30cf2f7e53cf7f07c.pdf

The approach is given by solving the follwing optimization problem

$(t,s,R)=\arg\min\limits_{t,s,R}\sum\limits_i^N\Vert Q''_i-Q'_i\Vert^2$,

s.t.   $Q'_i=sRQ_i+t$

where $Q''$ represents the one obtained by measurement$, s$ the scaling operation, $R$ the rotation, and $t$ the shift. The link above gives the close-formed solution of $s,Q,t$.

Share with someone with interest!

Comment: Fundamentally a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2314083/265466.

Comment: @amd, thanks! Almost the same. I even find a publication for this topic. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Construct an affine transformation of a plane given the images of three points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2314083/construct-an-affine-transformation-of-a-plane-given-the-images-of-three-points)

Comment: @Alex, thanks. It is the same link as amd posted above.

Comment: @Land I did not post that, that was something automatically posted when I confirmed that the link was correct in the review queue.  Must be some new algorithms implemented by StackExchange...

Comment: @Alex The automatic comment changed from “Possible duplicate...“ to this recently. I suppose it’s an attempt to make SE seem more “friendly.”

Comment: Your additions are an entirely different question from the original: Finding a best-fit transformation between two sets of affine points is a rather different process from computing an affine transformation between three point pairs. Please avoid mutating your questions like this in the future. Post a new question referring back to the original instead.